# Creating and storing a survey in Qt

Tags: c++, database, qt, survey

I am creating a desktop application as part of my final year project at university, using Qt.

It is a mystery shopping platform, where you log on to it, select a job to do (like go for a meal at a restaurant), and complete a survey based upon the experience.

Questions would be a range of things such as:
"Date and time of visit" 
"Was music playing at an appropriate volume? (easy to have a conversation but can still hear what’s playing)” 
"How would you rate the quality of the food /5?" 
etc

How/Where would I store these surveys? A database? But it could have ~60+ questions (and therefore columns.)
I’d also need to include the answers to the questions in it. 
Additionally, one of the unique aspects of this is that the surveys are tailor made for the client, where the surveys would be very different. so having a database would limit it.

I’m not sure the best way to progress with this, could you give me any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can approach this problem.

One of these is to have some sort of key-value storage for atomic values (quesitons, answers), or you could use some NoSQL database with JSON interchange.

If you don't want to use the database, I would suggest you one of the solutions we use for our current project. 
We use RabbitMQ as the message broker that pushes the Google Protobuf messages into the various Kafka topics.

That way we have the control over the Request/Reply flow of messages. Protobufs are also platform independent, so it would allow someone who would be using your application sending and fetching the protobuf data, and display it wherever(web, phone, another application). Kafka would give you a persistence you need, and it has a nice ability to replay everyting. 
So in theory you'd be able to see all the surveys from the beginning of time until now.

I don't know if this answers your question, or not, but I hope it gives you some insight.

Ah yes, and the links to the things I mentioned. 
[librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka)
[Simple AMQP for RabbitMQ](https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient)
[Protobuf for C++](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial)
For key-value we use [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb)
but you can use Redis or MemSQL.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful and has given me some areas to investigate.